# iOS - No context detected and sometimes unable to switch to WebView context when contexts are available

Tags: java, selenium, appium

Below is my code:

```
Set<String> contextNames1 = appiumDriver.getContextHandles();

for (String winHandle: appiumDriver.getWindowHandles()) {
    System.out.println(contextNames1);

    if (winHandle.contains("WEBVIEW")) {
        ((AppiumDriver) appiumDriver).context(winHandle);
        System.out.println("Switched to " + winHandle);
        appiumDriver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
    }
}
```

1. No contexts are detected. I added a `wait` statement but still not working
2. If contexts are detected, then I'm getting an exception saying that "Unrecognized WebView context"

Answer (score 0):

If you notice that the web context has a delay of appearing in the list of contexts, you can add a while loop that checks for a certain amount of time if there are 2 contexts (native and web) before switching to it.

```
int tries = 0;
while (driver.getContextHandles().size() < 2 && tries < 5) {
    Thread.sleep(500);
    tries++;
}
```

I believe you should first change the context to the web view:

```
driver.context("name_of_the_webview_context");
```

And only then start switching between WindowHandles (not 100% sure as I've never used this, it just feels more logical).

```
driver.switchTo().window("name_of_your_window_handle");
```

Comment: I tried but still contexts are not getting detected, tried for 10 tries also. I'm trying to execute my scripts in Kobiton real devices